# Differential equations of an electron moving in an electromagnetic wave

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

I would like to get the differential equation (Which solution is v the speed of the electron and using Newton's second law) for an electron where the only force applied on it is the electric part of electromagnetic force (we neglect the magnetic part).

In this situation I know the electric field :
$$\vec{E} = E_0 cos(\omega t -kz) \hat{e_x}$$

I started by writing the electrostatic force for this electron :

$$\vec{F_E} = q\vec E$$

Therefore, we can write:

$$\sum \vec F = m\vec a$$
$$q\vec E = m\frac{d\vec v}{dt}$$
$$qE_0 cos(\omega t -kz) \hat{e_x} = m\frac{d\vec v}{dt}$$

But the problem is that I don't see where the position or the speed could be on the other side.
Could someone please help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I don't see where the position or the speed could be.* You don’t see the $z$ on the left and the $\vec v$ on the right?

Comment: I do but the force is oriented toward the x axis so the electron should also move along it and v should be along the x axis too.

Comment: The only thing that should be in the direction of the force is the acceleration, and it is.

Comment: But if then it isn't really a differential equation since on the left side there's z and on the right side "d²x/dt²" ?

Comment: It’s one vector differential equation, or three differential equations for the components.

Comment: Yeah, but I still don't get it, on the right side, the only force is a force that depends on z and which direction is $$\hat e_x$$  and on the right side the speed  vector is three dimensional. But then it means that y and z component of the speed or of the acceleration are 0 ?

Comment: The $y$ and $z$ components of the acceleration are zero.